# This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and '() => string' have no overlap

Tags: angular

I have a JSON file that contains the following array of objects: https://pastebin.com/raw/prnChamA. The data contains keys called `postitoimipaikka` that I need to loop over in order to get only those objects that have a matching value in the key `postitoimipaikka`.

User inputs a string `postitoimipaikka` as a function parameter which is then used to loop over the JSON array of objects.

I am getting the following error in `atms.service.ts`: `This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'string' and '() => string' have no overlap`

on line:

```
if (d.postitoimipaikka == postitoimipaikka.toUpperCase) {
```

atms.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { atm } from '../app/atm.interface';

@Injectable()
export class ATMService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  url = "./assets/data.json";

  searchByMunicipalityName = (municipality: string): Promise<atm[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: atm[]) => {
        let list: atm[] = [];
        for (let d of data) {
          if (d.postitoimipaikka == municipality.toUpperCase) {
            lista.push(d);
          }
        }
        resolve(list);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }


}
```

If `toUpperCase` method is removed, user has to type the string in upper case which is not suitable, but would work otherwise.

Comment: Don't forget to call the method by adding the parentheses: `postitoimipaikka.toUpperCase()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is that your are not calling `toUpperCase`, you have to add parenthesis after it. Also, you define an array called `list`, but you are actually pushing to an array called `lista`.

You can refactor your code to this:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: atm[]) => {
        resolve(data.filter(d => d.postitoimipaikka == municipality.toUpperCase()));
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use filter() to extract objects from an array. My version is below:

```
searchByMunicipalityName = (municipality: string): Promise<atm[]> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: atm[]) => {
        const list: atm[] = data.filter(x => 
        x.postitoimipaikka === municipality.toUpperCase()); 
        resolve(list);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      })
    })
  }
```